# add value1 to value2 OR 0 (zero) to value2 if value1 IS NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

This is a example

```
SELECT
(time + (SELECT vector FROM vectors WHERE type=1)) AS modified_time
FROM times;
```

I want to add `vector` to `time` from the `vectors` table where the vector's type is 1.
Sometimes there is one vector with type set to 1 (always only one, that is why I didn't use `LIMIT` in the query), but sometimes there is no one vector with type set to 1.

In the second case, the sub-query in the query above will return null and so `time + null` will be `null`.

So I need to make a fallback in case the sub-query returns `null`, something like :

`... (time + ((SELECT vector FROM vectors WHERE type=1) OR 0)) AS modified_time`

How can I make that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is only one row, let's guarantee it using `max()` . . . then you can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT (time + (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(vector), 0) FROM vectors WHERE type = 1)) AS modified_time
FROM times;
```

There are other approaches, but I find this to be the simplest if you leave the subquery in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use COALESCE

```
SELECT
(time + COALESCE((SELECT vector FROM vectors WHERE type=1),0)) AS modified_time
FROM times;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to do this:

```
SELECT
(time + ISNULL(SELECT vector FROM vectors WHERE type=1),0 OR Other Subquery) AS modified_time
FROM times;
```

So If there are more than one Aplly SUM to vector:

```
SELECT
(time + ISNULL(SELECT SUM(vector) FROM vectors WHERE type=1),0 OR Other Subquery) AS modified_time
FROM times;
```